# Change View template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC for creating a web application.

I have 2 models: **fooA** and **fooB** (has an attribute of type **fooA**).
*Controllers* and *Views* generated automatically.

Now, I want to do a little change in the *create view* of **fooB**:

- If there are entries of **fooA** then the normal dropdown appears;
- If there are no entries of **fooA** then a button appears with the following behaviour:

  - Save the remaining input data;
  - Redirect to the **fooA** *create view*;
  - Redirect back to the **fooB** *create view* with the data restored.

I hope I did good job explaining.

My problems start with the question: should I be doing this change in the View or Controller "side"? Then how can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can do it in View by using Razor or jQuery, it depends, provide some source code.

Comment: I didn't include source code because it's pretty much the template created by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think this is what you want. When users navigate to the view containing `fooB`, display a `drop-down list` if it has data. If not, try to create the data for the `drop-down list`. Here is my suggestion.

1. When users navigate to the view containing `fooB`, just display the `drop-down list` (even if it is empty), and a button called `Add` (or whatever you want) next to it.
2. When users click `Add`, a pop-up appear, which contains necessary fields to cerate the data for the `drop-down list`.
3. When user click `Create`, just make an `Ajax` call to the server to create the data. Then, display the success or fail message and refresh the `drop-down list` for the new data if needed.

By doing this way, you do not have to redirect back and forward between pages, as well as try to maintain the data through the redirect process.

I hope you get what I mean. Feel free to leave questions if you find anything unclear.

Comment: I know it would be easier that way. The thing is that I need to redirect to the "Create view" and redirect back with the data restored. It's a requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you know if there are entries of **fooA** when page is loaded and it will not change, then you can simple use **Razor** `if` statement in your cshtml file:

```
@if (fooA != null)
{
    ...code with dropdown...
}
else
{
   ...code with button...
}
```

[Sample](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_cs_logic.asp)

Is this is what you are looking for?

Comment: That I know. My problem is with the "button action". I need to have that sequence of steps happening: save data, go to a page, redirect back with data restored. Thank you!

Comment: So maybe use Bootstrap modal as fooA editor (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing some of the comments, and the fact that the "fooA" must be created in a separate view.  Realistically, this is going to require both view and controller changes, but the bulk of the operations you'll need will be in a controller action.

There are dozens of options for this, but I this is the route I would take (so take it with a grain of salt):

- Have a `MyController.CreateFooB` action, which is your standard `[HttpPost]` action for creating the fooB model when fooA does not need to be created
- Have a `MyController.CreateFooBAndRedirectToFooA`, which is also an `[HttpPost]`

  - This action will need the fooB View Model as a parameter, and will create the model on your database or storage device
  - after the model is created, redirec to `MyController.CreateFooA` that is an `[HttpGet]` action, and pass the `FooB` model's ID to the action (that way you can perform a redirect back
  - After the user submits to `MyController.CreateFooA` with their `[HttpPost]`, create model A and perform **another** redirect to `MyController.EditFooB` so that the user can bind the new FooA to FooB

How you implement the `EditFooB` is very much up to you (passing A's ID and placing that into the update form, forcing the user to pick it out of the dropdown, etc). But ultimately with the workflow you described, you'll need to do a *Post to Create B* -> *Redirect to Create A* -> *Post to Create A* -> *Redirect to Update B*